# Storing encrypted files inside a database

Tags: python, database, security, encryption

I'm using PyCrypto to store some files inside a SQLITE database.

I'm using 4 fields :
the name of the file,
the length of the file (in bytes)
the SHA512 hash of the file
the encrypted file (with AES and then base64 to ASCII).

I need all the fields to show some info about the file without decrypting it.

The question is : is it secure to store the data like this ?
For example, the first characters of a ZIP file, or executable file are always the same, and if you already know the hash and the length of the file ... is it possible to decrypt the file, maybe partially ?

If it's not secure, how can I store some information about the file to index the files without decrypting them ? (information like length, hash, name, tags, etc)

(I use python, but you can give examples in any language)

Comment: note to save space and avoid the overhead of base64 (about 33% increase in size), you should use blobs to store binary data in an sqlite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid any problems concerning the first few bytes being the same, you should use AES in Block Cipher mode with a random IV. This ensures that even if the first block (length depends on the key size) of two encrypted files is exactly the same, the cipher text will be different.

If you do that, I see no problem with your approach.

Answer (score 3):

Data encrypted with AES has the same length as the plain data (give or take some block padding), so giving original length away doesn't harm security. SHA512 is a strong cryptographic hash *designed* to provide minimal information about the original content, so I don't see a problem here either.

Therefore, I think your scheme is quite safe. Any information "exposed" by it is negligible. Key management will probably be a much bigger concern anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just say "oah its AES-256 of course its secure."  Just by your post I can see that your confusing attacks against stream ciphers and block ciphers,  so you probably should **NOT** be implementing this until you acutally do research into this topic.

That being said you must read about [block cipher modes of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29). The entire [CWE-310](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/310.html) family.  It wouldn't hurt to pick up a copy of piratical cryptography.   After all of that there is still plenty of room for you to completely mess this up.

Real solution:  **USE SOMEONE ELSE'S IMPLEMENTATION**.

Comment: Thank you, i will search that book. As you guessed, i am a newbie in cryptography, I'm using other people's tools. I just want to keep my private data as private as possible. I'm salting the key and storing the salt and SHA512 key in database, along with the encrypted file and the tags. It must be safe. Using someone elses implementation is not a solution, unless you know a software that creates "portable encrypted compressed indexed containers" for files. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Cristi Constantin  i don't think thats a valid way of storing a key.   sha512 is one way,  you can't get the plain text,  if you hit it with sha512 again then so can the attacker.   Who needs access to the data?  Who are you trying to prevent from accessing the data?

Comment: @Rook: I read your profile so i won't disagree with anything you say :). Anyway, SHA512 is a one way function right? So if i salt the password (8 characters salt) and hash the result, it shouldn't be possible to use rainbow tables attack. The person who stored the files inside the database should be the only one that has access to the files. Noone else.

Comment: @Rook: I don't really have to store the hash and salt, i could just store the encrypted files, BUT let's say you type the password once (when you open the encrypted container) and the password is kept in memory as long as you keep the software running, if you want to open a file, the password in memory must be used to decrypt the file BUT you don't know if the password is correct until you execute the file somehow (AES encrypted files can be decrypted with wrong passwords as far as i know). So only if the file is executed correctly can you know that you typed the wright password.

Comment: @Rook: In conclusion, i must store something to check the password right before opening the container.

Comment: @Cristi Constantin So then why store the password?  Shouldn't the password be the key to store the files?

Comment: @Rook: The password is never stored. Only the salt and the hash are stored.

Comment: @Cristi Constantin Read about String to Key functions(sk2).  A passowrd must never be used as a encryption key,  its the hash of the key.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to think about what attacks you want to protect against, and the resources of the possible attackers.

In general, storing some data encrypted is only useful if it satisfies your exact requirements. In particular, if there is a way an attacker could compromise the key at the same time as the data, then the encryption is effectively useless.

Comment: Well, i just want my private data to be... as private as possible. Maybe i should use PGP instead of AES. Anyway, i got the answer i wanted. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @Cristi: you need to consider key management in your application; this is the main problem with using encryption.